# Use Wayland session with Lubuntu 21.04 on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: lubuntu, xorg, raspberrypi, wayland, sddm

I'm on a quest to find the best possible configuration for our Raspberry Pi 4B used almost exclusively to watch internet video streams. So far, I've tried getting the most out of Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS, Ubuntu and Lubuntu, with Lubuntu being a clear winner in terms of performance.

I read that the new Ubuntu 21.04 uses Wayland by default, however, after installing Lubuntu over it and using SDDM, the session is using Xorg.

I'm happy with the current setup (Lubuntu 64bit/SDDM/Xorg) but I'm curious if things could improve even further. I'm still learning so I'm not even sure the changes I'm proposing would even potentially make a difference.

What I would like to try is to use a Wayland session in Lubuntu using SDDM or GDM3. According to the SDDM documentation though, Wayland is not fully supported yet ([From SDDM documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SDDM)):

> Note: The Wayland windowing system is not yet fully supported [1].
> Wayland sessions are listed, but SDDM runs on X11.

I already know Ubuntu 21.04 uses Wayland and seemingly GDM3 so my question is: Is it possible to use GDM3 and Wayland on Lubuntu? I tried switching to GDM3 but it just boots me into Ubuntu with no way of choosing Lubuntu at login.

I don't even know if I'm on the right track here in terms of what I should be trying to accomplish so any insight would really help.

Comment: I haven't used Lubuntu for quite some time now so I may say things that aren't applicable. That said, if wayland is available for Lubuntu you can surely select it before logging in. Likewise, in standard Ubuntu with wayland now being the default you can always select xorg the same way.

Comment: Just out of noob curiosity, is that generally how it works? That is, no extra work should be done and whatever options that are available simply show up at login? I only ask cos I noticed the entries at login changed since 20.10 (although looking at the entry files themselves doesn't reveal anything specific about Wayland or Xorg) so I figured maybe I was just not applying some setting in some file or something to get Wayland to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.04 documentation refers to the default GNOME desktop (when talking about desktop and not servers) unless it's specifically talking about flavors (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/04/22/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-released/ where flavors are only briefly mentioned.

The [Ubuntu 21.04 release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221)  twice refer to Lubuntu

- referring you instead to [Lubuntu's release notes](https://lubuntu.me/hirsute-released/) for specific details,
- and where you can download Lubuntu.

You'll note Lubuntu is treated equally to all other *flavors* (ie. the release notes are about Ubuntu 21.04 Desktop (with GNOME), Ubuntu 21.04 Server, and not really the flavors).

Lubuntu 21.04 uses LXQt which currently uses X.Org as Wayland is still a work in progress (https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/10)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to check GitHub issues.